# Delphi StringGrid HighLight row and column

Tags: delphi

I have a StringGrid and I color on the fixed row and Column the position of the clicked cell. So it looks like this so far:

[image]

In order to do this I used this code:

```
procedure TForm2.sgDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  md: integer;
begin
  with sg do
    begin
   Canvas.Brush.Color:= clwhite;
   if ((sg.Row = ARow)and(ACol=0)) or ((sg.Col = ACol)and(ARow=0)) then
      Canvas.Brush.Color:= $00FFDE9B; //your highlighted color
   Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
   Canvas.TextOut(0, Rect.top + 4, cells[ACol, ARow]);
  end;
  if gdSelected in State then
    sg.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end;
```

plus of course the invalidate in OnMouseDown.

```
procedure TForm2.sgMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  sg.invalidate;
end;
```

Now, I want to color all the selected rows in the top side. So like in the image, there are 4 cells selected but only one cell is colored blue (Col 4) in the fixed area. I want all the corresponding fixed cells to be blue. (in this case: Col 4, Col 5, Col 6, Col 7)

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The idea is to show the selection when selecting with the mouse, not with SHIFT+Click

Comment: `if ((ACol = 0) and InRange(ARow, Selection.Top, Selection.Bottom)) or ((ARow = 0) and InRange(ACol, Selection.Left, Selection.Right)) then Canvas.Brush.Color := $00FFDE9B;` ?

Comment: in JediVCL there is a grid that has DefaultDrawCell method - so you only has to set colors in the event handler and call it

Comment: Or easier `if (gdFixed in State) and (InRange(ARow, Selection.Top, Selection.Bottom) or InRange(ACol, Selection.Left, Selection.Right)) then Canvas.Brush.Color := $00FFDE9B;`.

Comment: Guys, I asked the question wrong... I am looking for a way of coloring the said fixed cells when Mouse is used to select multiple cells

Comment: Changing the question makes my answer obsolete. Please don't do that.

Comment: Sorry LU RD... I am behind schedule and I do things too fast. When I posted the question I thought I asked it corectly, but I did not check to make sure

Answer (score 1):

Little improvement

```
procedure TForm3.sgDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  md: integer;
begin
  with sg do
    begin

   Canvas.Brush.Color:= clwhite;

   if ( (Arow >=selection.Top) and (Arow<=selection.Bottom) and(ACol=0)) or
      ( (ACol>=selection.Left) and (Acol<=selection.Right) and(ARow=0)) then
         Canvas.Brush.Color:= $00FFDE9B; //your highlighted color
   Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
   Canvas.TextOut(0, Rect.top + 4, cells[ACol, ARow]);
  end;
  if gdSelected in State then
    sg.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end;

procedure TForm3.sgMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
      if (ssLeft in shift) then sg.Invalidate;
end;
```

This will highlight the rows too whitout helper function.

Comment: Better subclass the control and override the `SelectionMoved` method. This way won't work for keyboard selection. I would consider [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/7jFgJ2ve).

Comment: It sounded great but I can't: Method 'SelectionMoved' not found in base class. Keep in mind that my base class is TStringGrid, and I use Delphi XE

Comment: Pity. Then they must have un-private it in some later release. Then I think you'll need some ugly hacks.

Comment: Ugly hacks... such as? Can you help?

Comment: Class Helpers is one possibility.

Comment: @LURD, I don't think you can override a private non-virtual method with class helper.

Comment: @TLama, it is a virtual protected method in TCustomGrid.

Comment: @LURD, if it was, you could override it. They must have change it between Delphi XE and XE3 as in XE3 it is virtual protected. In XE the OP reports it is not.

Comment: @TLama, if it is non-virtual protected, you can mark it with reintroduce.

Comment: @LURD, you can reintroduce it, but it won't be called from the base class. I'm afraid there's no way to override a private non-virtual method (at least not without some hack e.g. from Hallvard's cookbook).